# OWIN Startup Class

Tags: dependency-injection, owin

Can someone please tell me the exact role of the OWIN startup class. Basically what I am looking for :

- Whats its purpose
- When is it called, it is just once or per request
- Is this a good place to configure my Dependency Injection library.

Comment: refer this http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/getting-started-with-owin-and-katana

Comment: Thanks for the pointer I already went through this.  Can you please let me know if this is a good place to configure DI and if not where should I configure it?

Comment: what i am not getting is what is DI?

Comment: Dependency Injection (Autofac, Unity)

Comment: which technology are you using for this? i.e .Net: MVC or elz

Comment: I am using MVC WebAPI with AutoFac.  Also when does the Configuration method on the Startup class run? is it per request or once for the whole application?

Comment: this will explain you in detail http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25380/Dependency-Injection-with-Autofac

Answer (score 2):

Owin is designed to be pluggable deisgn. there are a set of services which you can change/replace from the configuration. For example in the following configuration, i have

- enabled webapi
- Enabled Signalr
- Enabled Attribute Based routing for Signalr
- Configured default Dependency Resolver
- Replaced Logging service with custom logger

So , this way, you can configure the complete configuration. It **will be called only once at startup**. You can set/use dependency resolver and configure it here, but that depends mainly on your overall design.

```
public class OwinStartup
{
    //initialize owin startup class and do other stuff
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseWelcomePage("/");
        //var container = new UnityContainer();

        HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
        httpConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "MyDefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/v2/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

        //Maps the attribute based routing
        httpConfiguration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        //Set the unity container as the default dependency resolver
        httpConfiguration.DependencyResolver = new UnityWebApiDependencyResolver(new UnityContainer());

        //replace (or add) the exception logger service to custom Logging service
        httpConfiguration.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new ExLogger());
        app.UseWebApi(httpConfiguration);

        //Add Signalr Layer
        app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration
        {
            EnableJSONP = true,
            EnableDetailedErrors = true
        });
    }

    public class ExLogger : ExceptionLogger
    {
        public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
        {
            base.Log(context);
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```